# Animated bounce icon in Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I'm trying to create an animation with the Markers in a Google Map in Android.

The desired effect is like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnlo0rynflmt5um/marker_gromia.gif?dl=0

Obviously I cannot set the gif as the marker's icon.. I have also all the frame of the animation but it's really heavy to use them. Any idea of how to accomplish this animation?

The final appearance of the number can be also more "static" instead of the effect that is showing. I don't ask for the code, but having a pointer/idea of how to do that would already be great.

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created XML objects and then I've animated them. It's the only way, it's too heavy with the images. This is the basic code (I haven't recreated the whole animation).

I think that it would be another solution to speed up the animation, but until now it's the only idea I came up with.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animateMarker(new LatLng(object.la, object.lo), object, numberOfClusters);
                    }
                }, delay*index);
```

Is the code that calls this function:

```
private void animateMarker(final LatLng position, final ClusterData object, final String clusterNumber) {
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .anchor(.5f, .5f);
    //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.pallino_msg, numberOfClusters)));

    int px = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cluster_size);

    int startValue = px;
    final int endValue = new Double(px * 1.5).intValue();

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startValue, endValue);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            String clusterGiven = "0";
            if (val == endValue){
                clusterGiven = clusterNumber;
            }
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(createBitmap(val,
                    BASE_ALPHA + (val * 20 / endValue), clusterGiven)));
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            clusters.put(marker.getPosition(), object);
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
}

protected Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, String text) {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.create("fonts/font.ttf", Typeface.BOLD);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(getActivity(), 11));

    Rect textRect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //If the text is bigger than the canvas , reduce the font size
    if (textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))     //the padding on either sides is considered as 4, so as to appropriately fit in the text
        paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(getActivity(), 7));        //Scaling needs to be used for different dpi's

    //Calculate the positions
    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

    //"- ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)" is the distance from the baseline to the center.
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2));

    canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);

    return bitmap;
}

public BitmapDescriptor createBitmap(int dimension, int alpha, String clusterNumber){
    Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dimension, dimension, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mDotMarkerBitmap);
    Drawable shape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_base_shape);
    shape.setAlpha(alpha);
    shape.setBounds(0, 0, mDotMarkerBitmap.getWidth(), mDotMarkerBitmap.getHeight());
    shape.draw(canvas);

    if (Integer.parseInt(clusterNumber) > 0){
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(mDotMarkerBitmap, clusterNumber));
    }

    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap);
}
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```